# React DevTools Anonymous displayName

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I need a `displayName` property for a React component. If not, React DevTools shows `Anonymous`. I attempted a separate line for `export` and `const Titlebar = function(props){...}`, no luck. Can DevTools read the function name directly without `displayName`?

```
export function Titlebar (props: TitlebarProps): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <h1 className={styles.titlebar}>
      <a href='/'>{props.title}</a>
    </h1>
  )
}

Titlebar.displayName = 'Titlebar'
```

Comment: It reads it directly, depends on how you render `TitleBar`, for example `React.memo(Titlebar)` displayName won't show `Titlebar`

Comment: Nothing fancy: ReactDOM.render( Diez Element -> div -> Titlebar, document.getElementById('root') )